# Is it possible to pass a custom position to calculate lighting in unity surface shaders?

Tags: unity-game-engine, hlsl, fragment-shader, vertex-shader

I want to create a shader that uses different coordinates for light calculations than for what's being displayed. This probably sounds strange, but I would like to do this for lighting a top-down 2D game.

I want to write a vertex shader that offsets the Z coordinate by the value of the Y coordinate for display, but uses unmodified coordinates for lighting calculation.

Is this possible to do, and if so, where would I start?

So far I have a surface shader that offsets the Z coordinate by the value of the Y coordinate, but unity is using the modified coordinates to calculate lighting, I would like unity to use the unmodified coordinates for light calculations.